# How to understand this "with"?

Tags: ocaml

```
 (** adds an header option in the header option list*)
 let add_headers header key value =
 { header with
   headers = Http_headers.add key value header.headers }
```

How to understand "header with headers ..." ?  I guess it "replace" the header.headers with a new headers.   Howerver, the passed header should be immutable, shouldnot it ?

Sincerely!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931496/x-with-value-in-ocaml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the passed `header` is (or can be) immutable. This function doesn't actually modify its argument; it just returns a copy of it, with the copy's `headers` field "replaced", as you say.

Comment: I think that all of most of the fields except 'headers' in this example will be shared between 'header' and the returned value.  For example, if one of the fields in 'header' is an array, modifying an element in that array will be reflected in all values sharing that array field.